# Why is it saying wrong number of columns selected in sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

So I'm in Code editor - SQL Query in Oracle Apex and when I write down the command

```
 "select product_name from product;"
```

Oracle is answering with error : "ORA-20999: Wrong number of columns selected in the SQL query. See help of attribute for details". Does anybody know what is the problem here?

Comment: I am assuming you have a table "product" with a column "product_name"? (we don't know anything about your system!)

Comment: this is the complete sql command or is only a part  .. if so show the rest too

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please supply:`CREATE TABLE/VIEW` statement for table/view `product`

Comment: Is this SQL query used to define region source, shared component or some page item? If it's item, what type of item is it?

Comment: I down voted because you haven't given enough information for a definite answer to be given.

Comment: You could try reading the **help of the attribute for details**...

Comment: @JeffreyKemp how can we find "help of the attribute" ?

Comment: Select the attribute, and open the Help tab (in the middle pane).

Answer (score 6):

It looks like a **list of values**.

If that's so, it requires EXACTLY two columns to be returned: a **display** value, and a **return** value. Therefore, it might look like this:

```
select product_name d,       --> display value
       product_id   r        --> return value
from product
```

Answer (score 1):

Select List Requires at least 2 Columns

1. Return Column
2. Display Column

If you want only one column you can do as follow.

```
select product_name,product_name "Product Name" from product;
```